# Signal recovery in Frequency domain?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication, telecommunication

Good day to everyone!

I am writing a matlab program in which I am doing OFDM symbol transmission through Fading channel :

```
Ncp=37;

Nfft=128 ; % size of fft

x = complex(randn(1,128), randn(1,128)); % the signal to be transmitted 

IFFT_Data =ifft(x); % OFDM Modulation

Tx =  [IFFT_Data((128-Ncp+1):128), IFFT_Data];

h=rand(1,600); % the fading channel 

y = conv(Tx,h); % transmission through channel 

received_signal = fft(y); % OFDM demodualtion
```

from this point i want to reconstruct my transmitted data as you see when we use fft that's mean we are in frequency doamin right ! 
then we need also to take fft , now we are obliged to work in frequency domain 
can you tell me how i can reconstruct my transmitted data  x

Comment: So, according to the convolution theorem conv(x,h) is fft(x)*fft(h)? aaah, very interesting. Try it. ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri : that's sure the circular convolution=the element wise product in frequency domain ;)

Comment: I know :D. What I wanted to say is, if you know how to do it, why dont you try it ;)

Comment: My problem is about signal recovery in frequency domain can you help me :)

Comment: I can help you, adn I know what your problem is about. I dont knwo your problem

Comment: Again, explain better your problem, please. Do you want to do fft(x)? because thats signal in frequenzy domain. see: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fft.html?refresh=true

Comment: Edit your question please

Comment: When I say edit the question I meant: go to the question in the top, click in the button `edit` and write it there. I cannot understand the code in a comment